# Create buttons which looks perfect in all the screen

Tags: android, button

i have five buttons at the bottom of the screen in table layout in android.
i want to display all this buttons same (height should be look proper)in all the screen of android, the following is code in xml file for footer, but the problem is buttons height looks stretched in htc one and samsung s4. how to solve this issue.

```
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3F689C"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/home" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_contact_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/contact_us_1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_about_us"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/about_us_1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_notification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/notification" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_setting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/setting" />
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Button size will obviously stretch according to the screen size since you have give width as `wrap_content` and height as `fill_parent`..

Comment: then what is the solution @Girish Gowda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You need to put the layout as a child of Relative Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/menu_layout" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/interactive_title_tabs"
            style="@style/PagerTitleStrip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/menu_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/grey_menu_backgroud"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_data_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_menu_button"
            android:text="@string/send_data" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sync_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_menu_button"
            android:text="@string/check_for_cmd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/apps_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_menu_button"
            android:text="@string/app_store" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code here, this pastebin could be  deleted.

Comment: ?I tried posting full code but it took just a part of the code. I pasted it and used the code tag in it and it was not working. Could you help me with it?

Comment: Done. It was not working earlier for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to create buttons to support multiple screen sizes.

Please go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) link which gives you enough information.

Normally android device screen is divided into four categories.

*xlarge* screens are at least 960dp x 720dp

*large* screens are at least 640dp x 480dp

*normal* screens are at least 470dp x 320dp

*small* screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

So if you want to design your app to support to all these screen sizes then you need four separate layout files.

That is

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")

res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size

res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size

res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

you can provide different width and height for different screens.

The appropriate layout will be selected automatically by android system.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use 9-patch images, so you can adjust the only areas of image which will be stretched or not.
Take a look at here for further information.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html